# Slow Performance When Changing Object Data [2.8]

Tags: performance

I'm not sure if it's the object data actually, but I couldn't think of a better way to phrase it. Whenever I ctrl+z, change materials, open/close the file, make or change collections, etc, it takes way too long. It says the program has stopped responding for about ten seconds, then starts responding again. It doesn't do this when moving objects in the 3D viewport or tabbing in/out of edit mode, etc. Furthermore, it's only with this file. My other files, despite being more complex and taking up more space, don't do this.
Any help/suggestions are much appreciated.

Apologies for my last post btw

[Download](https://www.mediafire.com/file/v8vf40biucs1p0z/BAD_apple_segment_3.blend/file)
[image]

Comment: Excatly which version are you using. I think a encountered a similiar problem in an older version when using a few subdivisions. Also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89659/blender-global-undo-is-very-slow-on-complex-scenes

Comment: I'm using blender-2.80.0-git.d525c76003b3-windows64. I enabled simplify, didn't change anything. I had a sub-surf modifier on her body, yes, but I had it disabled in the viewport. To test it out, I deleted the modifier entirely. Didn't change anything either.

Comment: Also, that problem only specified problems with undoing. My problem is with much more. Can't even quickly add/delete objects.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I think I found the solution! The collision objects for the legs had wayyy too many vertex groups. After deleting the armature modifier, everything went back to normal speed. I cleared the vertex groups, except the ones I needed, and gave it the armature modifier again. Now everything works as it should.